# Set in the middle a div inside another div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have the following piece of HTML page:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="description">
        Some text
    </div>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
#main {
    height:600px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

#description {
    display:block;
    height:50%;
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    font-size:18px;
}
```

With this code, `description div` is centered horizontally, but I want to center it vertically.

Do you know how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css `display:table-cell` write like this

```
 #main {
    height:600px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/weGGn/9/

You can also use `position:absolute` but in this case you have to define `height` of that `div`. check this article http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Check this article http://www.student.oulu.fi/~laurirai/www/css/middle/ may be that's help your

Answer (score 1):

You can use relative-absolute positioning to achieve this:

```
#main
{
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: lime;
}
#description
{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%; /* (100 - width)/2 */
    top: 25%; /* (100 - height)/2 */
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

## [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/aNdUd/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use table-cell - but it is only supported in newer browsers. I'm not sure on the version numbers (but I think it's like IE8+ and FF6+)

But if you're not worried about compatibility with old browsers use table-cell. Otherwise you have to use negative margins and stuff like that.

You can read about it here: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
#main {
   height:600px;
   width:600px;
   background-color: blue;
   position: absolute;
}

#description {
   display:block;
   height:50%;
   width: 50%;
   margin: 25% auto;
   position:relative;   
   font-size:18px;
   background-color: red;
```

}

jsfiddle  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3TEPn/1/)